# What tense is a good choice for these sentences: past simple or past perfect?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

But when I saw the very thin packaging I thought that it was a miracle that the record **was not broken**.

But when I saw the very thin packaging I thought that it was a miracle that the record **had  not been broken** during the transport.

But when I saw the very thin packaging I thought that it was a miracle that the record **was not broken** during the transport.

Are these sentences correct which is the best(specially for the verbs in bold).
I don't think the last one is good because the transport happened before the miracle so had been broken during the transport is better.

Comment: Either (1) or (2) is fine. (1) implies 'the record was not in a broken condition when I unpacked it'.